# 2018 equivalent of jQuery's basic sizzle selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Seeing as it's 2018, I am trying to move away from jQuery for a lot of basic tasks. That said, its sizzle selector remains one of the quickest, most intuitive ways to convert a css selector to an actual DOM node I can manipulate with javascript.

Is there a quick way using Vue.js* to select a class of object? I know there are browser-native ways to do this, but I'm hoping for something nearly as brief, flexible and cross-platform as `jQuery('.myclassname')` and `jQuery('#myclassname')`.

(Note that I typed less than a dozen characters outside of my css-style selector and didn't have to change the command when switching from a class to an id.)

**Does Vue° have this? If so, how do I access it?**

====

*I'm specifically asking about Vue rather than React or Angular because popular opinion seems to have Vue as the quickest to adopt on small projects. That doesn't mean it's the 'best' framework -- just that it fits my particular use case.

°If there's a browser-native function that fulfills the requirements I've outlined for flexbility and brevity, I would of course also be interested in that.

Comment: Perhaps it's [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) you are looking for? It's been part of the web-standard for some time now.

Comment: Thanks. I like document.querySelector and document.querySelectorAll, but they're quite long. Maybe I'll just alias them so I don't have to retype them all the time. I was hoping that maybe a framework was already doing this -- one less line to type out if so.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, you don't ever manipulate the DOM with VueJS.  Your component data should drive the DOM, using the data to calculate which classes are on an element or which elements are visible. But I would say the Vue equivalent of your question would be refs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs

You can put a ref on an element and reference it in js:

```
<div id="parent">
  <user-profile ref="profile"></user-profile>
  <table ref="table"></table>
</div>

var parent = new Vue({ el: '#parent' })

var child = parent.$refs.profile
var table = parent.$refs.table
```

Comment: This is something a lot of people seem to miss about React/Vue/etc. If you're tweaking the DOM, you're probably not using them to their full potential.

Comment: Agreed completely, ceejayoz. But tweaking the dom can be a precursor for more advanced things. That "gateway drug" status is one of the things many people like about Vue :-)

Comment: Just to append more information to this answer: You cannot access the refs inside the `created` function, as that is before the component has rendered, the first point you can access them is inside the `mounted` hook, as this is after the rendering (feel free to add this directly to your answer, attribution optional)